# IP warmup question

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability, sender-authentication-package, ip, ip-warming

I've created the following table of the most common email domains in my country.

[image: IP Warmup]

I am wondering if this approach would be a good one? Especially for Gmail and Microsoft.

Previous warmups have been a little rough even when following the Salesforce recommendations. 
According to Salesforce support it would be best practice to have a continuous flow (as in send daily).

Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers seem to be fine, but I would advise to utilize **Send Throttling** on top, so you wouldn't send all the Emails out at once during the warmup period.

Send Throttling can be enabled for Journey Builder Email Sends as well, in case it's currently not available in the UI.

Check the [official FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313195&type=1&language=en_US&mode=1) and download the Warming Guide PDF from Salesforce at bottom of article.